# Send a Json object from kotlin to php but recieve a null object in php server

Tags: php, android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to send a Json object from kotlin to my php server. My problem is that I recieve a null object in php. I have read similar questions but none of them solved my problem. This is my code in kotlin:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

        //-------------------------------------------------
        val issueJson = JSONObject()
        issueJson.put("issueLine", "123")
        issueJson.put("issueActivity", "Main")
        issueJson.put("issueFragment", "map")
        issueJson.put("issueExplanation", "---")


        val call = apiService.test(issueJson)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<TestInfo> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<TestInfo>, response: Response<TestInfo>) {
                Log.d("test", "ok")
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("test", response.body().toString())
                } else {
                    Log.d("test", response.errorBody().toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<TestInfo>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("test", "no")
                Log.d("test", t.toString())
            }

        }
        )
//-------------------------------------------------
data class TestInfo(
    val issueLine:String,
    val issueActivity:String,
    val issueFragment:String,
    val issueExplanation:String
)
//-------------------------------------------------
interface ApiService {
    @POST("hamrahenet/test.php")
    fun test(@Body body: JSONObject): Call<TestInfo>
}
```

And this is my code in php:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo json_encode($array);
```

I recieve this result in Kotlin:`D/test: ok D/test: TestInfo(lineNumber=null, activityName=null, fragmentName=null, isueExplanation=null)`

Which the value of all keys are null.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing `JSONObject` and using `TestObject` both for sending and receiving. Your PHP code seems to echo the same content it receives, but the JSON you are sending bears little resemblance to the JSON that you expect to receive.

```kotlin
        val issueJson = JSONObject()
        issueJson.put("issueLine", "123")
        issueJson.put("issueActivity", "Main")
        issueJson.put("issueFragment", "map")
        issueJson.put("issueExplanation", "---")
```

This creates a JSON object with fields named `issueLine`, `issueActivity`, `issueFragment`, and `issueExplanation`.

```kotlin
data class TestInfo(
    val lineNumber:String,
    val activityName:String,
    val fragmentName:String,
    val isueExplanation:String,
)
```

None of those properties match the JSON fields. The closest is `isueExplanation`, which is very similar to `issueExplanation`, but they are not the same. For Gson to parse the incoming JSON into a `TestInfo` object, the JSON fields need to match the `TestInfo` properties.

Comment: I changed the property names in data class to match exactly the field names in json object. But again I recieve the same result.

Comment: @Sara-Omidvar: Your next step should be to do some logging. Add [the OkHttp logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to your Retrofit setup and see what you are sending for JSON and what you are receiving. Also, consider logging on the server side to see what `$json` and `$array` are. Note that your JSON is not a JSON array, so `$array` is an unusual name to use here.

Comment: I changed $array to $issueReport. In fact, I echo $issueReport to see it's value in kotlin, Is there any other way to do server side logging?

Comment: @Sara-Omidvar: Sorry, I am an Android expert, and I know very little about PHP.